# How can I detect if a lexical variable exists (is declared) in a package, even if uninitialized?

Tags: perl, variables, variable-declaration

Let's say I have something

```
package Foo;
my $bar;
```

How can I tell if `$bar` is declared regardless of the fact that it's uninitialized?

At some level I assume it's possible because `warnings` knows it, here`warnings` knows the variable `$bar` exists, so you get an only an uninitialized warning.

```
$ perl -wE'my $bar; print $bar;'
Use of uninitialized value $bar in print at -e line 1.
```

But the `once` warning class knows here that the variable `$baz` isn't even declared.

```
$ perl -wE'my $bar; print $baz;'
Name "main::baz" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $baz in print at -e line 1.
```

Likewise, `strict` will just stop this from compiling so it too must know this (notice the `die` never triggers).

```
$ perl -wE'use strict; my $bar; print $baz; die 42;'
Global symbol "$baz" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $baz"?) at -e line 1.
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

So it too must know this.

Comment: Just a thought, let's ignore possibility of package and lexical sharing the same variable name, take reference of variable, and check whether it exists in current package hash table.

Comment: @Сухой27 The package hash table doesn't have lexical variables. It only has package variables (`our`)

Comment: That's the point, if you don't find something there then you've took reference to a lexical.

Comment: that's a really good idea. make that an answer @Сухой27

Comment: @Сухой27 actually that won't work either, taking a reference to a variable declares it as a package variable without strict `perl -wE'say \$foo; say scalar \${%{main::}{foo}}'`

Comment: Have you tried using the `PadWalker` module? There's no built-in way to do reflection on lexical variables in Perl, so you need some XS code.

Comment: There is some misleading terminology here that might be confusing the issue. First: there are package variables and pad (lexical) variables. Package variables exist by being used, not by being declared. The "once" warning comes about when a package variable is referenced only once in a program's execution, since you are not using strict your third example uses and thus vivifies a package variable in the current package, no declaration necessary.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to determine whether a *lexical* variable has been declared, which is one of the things strict 'vars' requires. To detect this programatically, you need to look at the pad with something like PadWalker. The pad has no relation whatsoever to any package stashes, only lexical scopes.

Comment: To add--  while you can check (`perl -MPadWalker=peek_my -Mstrict -wE'my $p = peek_my(0); exists $p->{ q($v) } ? say "Got \$v"  : say "No \$v"'`) I'm afraid that this may still be useless -- you still can't _use_ that variable anywhere in code, since if it doesn't exist the code won't compile, regardless of whether the use is "conditional."

Comment: @Evan Carroll, Re "*It only has package variables (`our`)*",  `our` variables are lexical variables (which are aliased to package variables).

Comment: @Grinnz, Re "*there are package variables and pad (lexical) variables*", Pad variables aren't necessarily lexical variables. The pad also includes target variables (used by some ops to return values), and these aren't lexical variables (at least not in the conventional sense)

Comment: @Evan Carroll, Re "*So it too must know this.*", Yes, of course the compiler knows about lexical variables exists. That doesn't mean that information is available at run time.

Answer (score 3):

`PadWalker` can inspect what lexical variables have been defined.

```
use PadWalker ':all';
my $foo;

my $level = -1;
while (my $pad = eval { peek_my(++$level) }) {
    print "$_ is declared in scope $level\n" for keys %$pad;
}
```

---

```
$level is defined in scope 0
$foo is defined in scope 0
```

Comment: Explanation: Perl doesn't free lexical variables on scope exit or sub exit. They continue existing in the sub's [scratchpad](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#Scratchpads) aka pad. (In fact, there's a pad for each level of recursion a sub has reached, so there could be multiple copies of a var in existence, even when the sub isn't actually running!) While variables are looked up by index into the pad, the var's name is present there (which is used in some error/warning message). `peek_my` and `peek_our` navigate the pads of subs. (Remember that `our` vars are lexical vars too!)

Comment: Do note that a sub could access multiple vars with the same name, and these vars could be a mix of lexicals and non-lexicals. As such, this could fail depending on where/when it's used.

Answer (score 2):

Without needing Padwalker (prints "is lex" once):

```
package Foo;

print "is lex\n" if eval('\\$' . __PACKAGE__ . '::foo') != \$foo;
my $foo;
print "is lex\n" if eval('\\$' . __PACKAGE__ . '::foo') != \$foo;
```

Comment: Fails for lexicals that are aliased to a package variable of the same name. (Ex1: `our $foo` Ex2: `use experimental qw( refaliasing ); \my $foo = \$foo;`) Also fails if the package var is the one that's aliased. (`*foo = \my $foo;`) Does it matter? I don't know. I have no idea why code would care whether a var is a lexical or not.

Answer (score 2):

To be clear, a lexical variable is not part of any package and does not interact with the package system at all; it's a completely different accounting. It belongs to the scope that it is in regardless of any package declaration. That scope is either the enclosing braces, the subroutine that declared it, or the file.

Most of the examples you show (`once` and `strict`) deal with package variables. For that, you can just look in the stash to see if the name is defined.

For the uninitialized case, perl sees that the variable has no value when it tries to use it.

Answer (score 2):

```
package Foo;
my $x;
my $eval_fmt = 'use strict; %s || 1';
eval( sprintf $eval_fmt, '$y' ) or warn 'No such variable: $y';
eval( sprintf $eval_fmt, '$x' ) and warn 'Variable $x exists';
```

Comment: That will fail for a declared package variables (`use vars qw( $x );`) aka imported package variables (`use Config qw( %Config );`)